# Error with saving new entity in Nest with TypeOrm, Postgresql

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, typeorm, nest

Before this bug i putted only one user to chat, it worked.
Now even when I'm trying to put only one user there's still error...

Even backups gives me same error
Entity:

```
import {Column, Entity, JoinTable, ManyToMany, ManyToOne, OneToMany, OneToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn} from "typeorm";
import {User} from "./user.entity";
import {Order} from "./order.entity";

@Entity()
export class Chat {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ManyToMany(() => User)
    @JoinTable()
    users: User[];

    @OneToOne(() => Order, (order) => order.chat, {nullable: true})
    order: Order
}
```

Service:

```
async createChat(userId, employeeId, orderId) {
        try {
            const candidateUser = await this.user.findOne({
                where: {
                    id: userId,
                },
            });

            const candidateEmployee = await this.user.findOne({
                where: {
                    id: employeeId,
                },
            });

            const candidateOrder = await this.order.findOne({
                where: {
                    id: orderId,
                },
            });

            if (candidateOrder && candidateUser && candidateEmployee) {
                const newChat = new Chat();
                newChat.users = [candidateEmployee];
                newChat.order = candidateOrder;

                const savedChat = await this.chat.save(newChat);

                candidateUser.currentChat = savedChat.id;
                candidateEmployee.currentChat = savedChat.id;

                await this.user.save(candidateUser);
                await this.user.save(candidateEmployee);

                candidateOrder.status = 'pending';

                await this.order.save(candidateOrder);

                return savedChat;
            } else {
                throw new Error('Не удалось создать чат.');
            }
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }
```

Error:
[Nest] 25302  - 07.10.2023, 17:27:24   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] UpdateValuesMissingError: Cannot perform update query because update values are not defined. Call "qb.set(...)" method to specify updated values.
Error: UpdateValuesMissingError: Cannot perform update query because update values are not defined. Call "qb.set(...)" method to specify updated values.
at ChatService.createChat (/mnt/hdd/web projects/telegram-monolith/telegram-server/src/chat/chat.service.ts:64:19)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at /mnt/hdd/web projects/telegram-monolith/telegram-server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
at /mnt/hdd/web projects/telegram-monolith/telegram-server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17

Answer (score 0):

You should add `@JoinColumn` in `order`

```
@Entity()
export class Chat {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ManyToMany(() => User)
    @JoinTable()
    users: User[];

    @OneToOne(() => Order, (order) => order.chat, {nullable: true})
    @JoinColumn()
    order: Order
}
```